# How to display menu link language in List Link view of menu?

Tags: 7, hooks, forms, navigation

We have a menu, Main Menu. When we view List Links of that menu we can see all the menu links. However, we do not know which menu link is associated to what language.

What would it take to make the page also display the language on the List Links Display? WE tried to modify the menu.admin.inc file to include the language value that is not working.

Page of interest: admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at making significant changes to the form builder [`menu_overview_form`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!menu!menu.admin.inc/function/menu_overview_form/7.x) (e.g. via [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x)) or perhaps a complete replacement at the menu route **admin/structure/menu/manage/%menu** handler (e.g. [`hook_menu_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7.x)) in [`menu_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!menu!menu.module/function/menu_menu/7.x).

Looking at the form builder shows the scope of the problem, it is making DB query that you'll need to augment with relevant logic for combining with language column. In addition, there is helper function, [`_menu_overview_tree_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!menu!menu.admin.inc/function/_menu_overview_tree_form/7.x) that builds out the form elements that is coupled with the `$tree` structure that's coupled with the result of DB query.

Given that, it might be easier for you to replace the route handler with your own custom form than trying to hack around the existing form. You certainly don't want to start hacking menu.admin.inc as your question implies.